# failed to convert a for loop into loop comprehension expression. why is my list comprehension slower than my for loop?

Tags: python, list, sliding-window

While building a project that uses sliding window, I have the following code, which works fine:

```py
#aby is a one dimension list like, eg:[0.010,0.012,0.008,......,0.009]
adj_qth_amp = 100
scan_window_size = 10000
wanted_time_stamps = []
window_sum = sum(aby[:scan_window_size])
for i in range(len(aby)-scan_window_size):
    window_sum = window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]
    if window_sum > adj_qth_amp:
        wanted_time_stamps.append(i)

#runtime is 4 minutes
#returns a wanted_time_stamps list that has valid elements after execution
```

then I remember people have a cool way of building a list like:

```py
my_list = [i for i in range(10)]              #basic list
my_list_2 = [i+1 for i in my_list]            #calculation
my_list_3 = [i+1 for i in my_list_2 if i>3]   #adding a condition
```

hence I wrote the following for practice:

```py
wanted_time_stamps = [(window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]) for i in range(len(aby)-scan_window_size) if (window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]) > adj_qth_amp]

#runtime is 8 minutes
#returns a wanted_time_stamps that is empty (eg.[]) after execution
```

I understand that this can be too long of a blob to make this a good way of making the list. but it was for practice.

Question:

1. what did I do wrong for the second method to return an empty list?
2. why is the runtime for the second method aproximately twice as long? isn't list comprehension suppose to be faster?

3.what is this way of declaring a list called? I am having a hard time searching about it, and thus naming my question here. edit: it is called list comprehension.

Comment: The name for that type of expression is a list comprehension.

Comment: [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Second method is longer because in your realization you add one data item and subtract one in every iteration. And in second realization the whole array sum is calculated at every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You update `window_sum` each time in the loop of the first way, but you do not do so in the second way.
2. In the second way, you calculate `(window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i])` twice each time in the loop.
3. [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

The correct way by using list comprehension:

```
[i for i in range(len(aby) - scan_window_size) if (window_sum := window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]) > adj_qth_amp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code with some sample data:

```
from math import sin

aby = [sin(i/900) for i in range(11000)]

adj_qth_amp = 100
scan_window_size = 10000
wanted_time_stamps = []
window_sum = sum(aby[:scan_window_size])
for i in range(len(aby)-scan_window_size):
    window_sum = window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]
    if window_sum > adj_qth_amp:
        wanted_time_stamps.append(i)

print(len(wanted_time_stamps))

window_sum = sum(aby[:scan_window_size])  # reset this variable to its initial value
wanted_time_stamps_comprehension = [
    i
    for i in range(len(aby)-scan_window_size)
    if (window_sum := window_sum - aby[i] + aby[scan_window_size+i]) > adj_qth_amp
]

print(wanted_time_stamps_comprehension == wanted_time_stamps)
```

Note that you update `window_sum` in every iteration - a way to do that in the list comprehension would be to update it with a walrus operator as shown.

Before the list comprehension, `window_sum` is reset to its initial value. The resulting list is identical - if it's actually the list you want though, I'm not sure. But if your original code was correct, so is the comprehension.

Output:

```
580
True
```

i.e. for 580 out of a possible 1,000 positions, the condition is true - and the two lists are identical.

Note that I named the new variable `wanted_time_stamps_comprehension`, but of course by the time the statement completes, it's resolved to a list just like the other.